# CS0433 Compilation Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

> Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The
>   type 'mmet.rgen' exists in both
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\mail\d77eac0c\a5fb2812\assembly\dl3\c6e9aa33\e7f7b4c8_463acc01\WebMail.DLL'
>   and
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\mail\d77eac0c\a5fb2812\App_Code.n0dshhx5.dll'

I created an web application in Visual studio 2010 and copied that code in to my project which is running on its own compiler using a batch file. After I am running this application in IIS 7.5 I am getting this error. I reinstalled OS and tried but no use. When I delete temporary files in .NET framework folder I am getting an error as "Source not found"

Comment: +1 funny for "I reinstalled OS and tried but no use."

Comment: @Ed - What to do? its such an important for me... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar message with Microsoft Report Viewer, this is caused when you have a reference in your web.config to lets say to version 10, and yet in one of your aspx pages you have a reference to verion 11.

If you have this you will get the type of error you are showing above. Make sure all you versions are the same. As you can see in the example below, at the top of the page you could be making a reference to a different verions.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="EarlyDeparture_DepartmentReport.aspx.cs" Inherits="Reports_LateArrival_LateArrival_DepartmentReport_01" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms,  Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="100%">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your bin file, you might need to clean the dll in their thats cuasing the problem. It looks like it's the webmail.dll that is causing the problem, see where you are using that dll and check if you have references on your page, and see if they match what you have in your web.config file.

Comment: Do a seach for mmet.rgen in your project and see if you can find any references.

Comment: Press Ctrl+F, then type in mmet.rgen.

Comment: okay but its a .cs file used in App_Code folder creating this trouble

Comment: It looks like it, it seems as if you have a type that matches a type you already have in one of the assemblies you are referencing.

Comment: No I will tell you in clear, I created an Class file in VS2k10 and added that Class file to my prior project where I got the above error that mmet.rgen exists in both the places. I tried deleting a file at .NET temp but it shown me an error "Source not found" when I deleted the bin folder I am getting errors with other files as 'this not found/ that not found. etc'.